# Mysql Subqery issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having an issue with a subquery.

I am making a best of 10 time trials league for my local cycling club. There is a weekly league where people who enter have their times recorded onto a table with their time.

Here is my stored procedure.

```
BEGIN
    #Routine body goes here...
        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_Temp;

        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_Temp (
        UserId int DEFAULT 0,
        TotalTime DECIMAL (10,2),
        EventCount int DEFAULT 0,
        FullName VARCHAR(255),
        Marshalled TINYINT(2) DEFAULT 0,
        HillClimb TINYINT(2) DEFAULT 0,
        Year INT(10)
        );

        INSERT INTO tbl_Temp (UserID,Year)
        SELECT DISTINCT userId,YEAR(date)
        FROM tbl_series;

        /* ---- EVENT COUNT */
        UPDATE tbl_Temp AS c,tbl_series AS t
        SET c.EventCount = (SELECT COUNT(userId) FROM tbl_series WHERE (UserID = t.userId))
        WHERE c.UserID = t.userId;

        /* ---- get the times into a temp table */


        /* ---- TOTAL TIME */
        UPDATE tbl_Temp AS c,tbl_series AS t
        SET c.TotalTime = (
            /*SELECT SUM(A.Time) FROM (
                    SELECT Time FROM tbl_series
                    WHERE (UserID = t.userId) 
                    LIMIT 10
                ) AS A*/
                SELECT SUM(Time) FROM tbl_series 
                WHERE (userId = t.UserId)
        )
        WHERE c.UserID = t.userId;

        /* ---- Name */
        UPDATE tbl_Temp AS c,tbl_users AS t
        SET c.FullName = (
                SELECT NAME
                FROM tbl_users
                WHERE (userId = t.UserId)
        ) 
        WHERE (c.userId = t.UserId);

        /* ---- Marshalled */
        /*  will need to add in a new table for marshalled so isn't lost over the coming years */
        UPDATE tbl_Temp AS c,tbl_users AS t
        SET c.Marshalled = (
                SELECT marshalled
                FROM tbl_users
                WHERE (userId = t.UserId)
        ) 
        WHERE (c.userId = t.UserId);

        /* ---- Hill Climb */
        UPDATE tbl_Temp AS c,tbl_users AS t
        SET c.HillClimb = (

            SELECT Count(tbl_series.SeriesID)
            FROM tbl_series
            INNER JOIN tbl_series_courses ON tbl_series.CourseID = tbl_series_courses.SeriesCourseID AND tbl_series.CourseID = tbl_series_courses.SeriesCourseID
            where (EventType = 2) AND (userId = t.UserId)

        ) 
        WHERE (c.userId = t.UserId);

        /* ---- select all */
        SELECT * FROM tbl_Temp

        ORDER BY EventCount Desc,TotalTime;

END
```

tbl_series which stores times, userID and the courseID

Am building a stored procedure up which works out the users, their total time etc however I wish for ONLY their top 10 fastest times but MySql has a limit to it. I can't run the following code.

```
/* ---- TOTAL TIME */
        UPDATE tbl_Temp AS c,tbl_series AS t
        SET c.TotalTime = (
            SELECT SUM(A.Time) FROM (
                    SELECT Time FROM tbl_series
                    WHERE (UserID = t.userId) 
                    LIMIT 10
                ) AS A
        )
        WHERE c.UserID = t.userId;
```

I get the error back

Procedure execution failed

> 1054 - Unknown column 't.userId' in 'where clause'

Any ideas would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh...Simple, MySql do not support `LIMIT` in inner queries.
Open a cursor, loop on the main result set and fetch the needed data for each record in the loop.